# How to work with cmd in session mode using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess

Question: is there any options to hold the session using Subprocess or else module?
It runs only one instruction or command per time.
I can't find any direct solution. Why it works only so?
It's same question for Windows, Linux and Mac OS-s.

Example 1.
I need to do some work in cmd with admin rights.

```
from subprocess import run, Popen, call
run('net user Administrator /active: yes', shell=True)
run('pip install [some module]', shell=True)  # or "powershell -command [some command]"
```

Example 2.
I need to use virtual env module and get in needed environment.

```
run(["workon", "Universal"]
run("[some changes]")
```

There is a CMD module, but it looks isolated from system cmd-terminal,like your own created CLI, and having a different purpose.

Please don't answer about bash scripts, or other options to get administrator rights, or about launching scripts from cmd itself like ">python main.py". There is talking about the sequential habitual execution of commands from CMD and how can Python do this, hold the cmd session, or it can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried one more time, and it seems it works! Holds the session!!
I used:

```
Popen("workon Universal", shell=True)   #  1
Popen("pip install termcolor")   # 2 without shell=True
```

And that finally installed a module on "Universal" virtual environment. And i can endless continue the Popen(3), Popen(4).
Same works with run().
It's all about right using the "shell=True" attribute.
I guess that is the solution i looked for. And it's universal for all commands and sessions. That's hard to understand, no any example on google or youtube.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want keep administrative privileges once gained.
I don't know about windows, don't use it.
But if i try something similar on Linux, i only have to type the admin password once:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run("sudo ls", shell=True)
[sudo] password for <me>: 
a.txt  b.txt
CompletedProcess(args='sudo ls', returncode=0)
>>> subprocess.run("sudo ls", shell=True)
a.txt  b.txt
CompletedProcess(args='sudo ls', returncode=0)
>>>
```

But your actual question is if you can 'hold the session'.

That is, if I understand you correctly, execute some commands in a shell, keep the shell running after those commands have finished, while you do something else in your script to generate extra commands, and then send these new commands to the same old shell

Yes that is possible.

You can use `subprocess.Popen()` to spawn an interactive shell (i.e. the shell is the command to execute)
and write actual commands to it's stdin and read results from stdout

If that sounds complicated: yes it is!
e.g. proper error handling means parsing the text returned by the shell, compared to simply check the return code for a synchronous call. Even detecting if your command has finished requires monitoring what appears on the shell stdout/stderr

You don't want to go down the asynchronous road.
Synchronous calls to external commands (such as `subprocess.run()`), without any shell in between, is so much simpler.